# Command to uninstall .pkg in solaris server

Tags: solaris

How to uninstall .pkg in solaris?
We have command to install pkgadd -d one.pkg,. Similarly can we have command for uninstall?

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way as the name of the file containing the package can be anything.
You need to retrieve the package name to be able to remove it.

This can be done with that oneliner (ksh or bash):

```
# pkgrm $(pkginfo -d one.pkg | nawk '{print $2}')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pkgrm <pkg_name>
```

To know package name run below command

```
pkginfo -l <word_in_package_name>
```